# How to query SQL database from SharePoint Dataview Webpart

Tags: jquery, sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to query a SQL database from a SharePoint web part? This is the scenario: 
I created a SharePoint custom list, and a data view web part. This list has several columns such as Name, Last Name, Address, etc. One of the columns is called "Customer_number".  There is a SQL database that contains pretty much the same fields as my list, and I would like to check the info entered or missing against this database using the "Customer_number" as reference. If the info entered in the web form is incorrect or missing, the data from the SQL database will replace it. Is it possible to this this? Can anyone give me some reference? I’ve been searching on the internet and I get so many different responses that I really don’t know what else to do. Thanks!

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing would normally be done as an `External Content Type`, otherwise the only way to insert such data in a custom list would be by using an `External Data` field that in its turn will fetch an `External Content Type`.

Check this, [MSDN: What Are External Content Types?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556391%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's a good start. I think that the External Data option sounds promising. I'll give it a try and let you know if I have any luck. Hopefully, it would helpful to others.